# Function pointer doubt

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-value

Please tell me what will the call to given function return and how? The code:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    ptrdiff_t index;
    void (*inlet) ();
    int argsize;
    ptrdiff_t argindex;
} CilkProcInfo;


/*
 * Returns a pointer to the slow version for a procedure
 * whose signature is p.
 */

/* the function definition is - */
static void (*get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p)) () {
     return p[0].inlet;
}

/*The function gets called as -*/
   (get_proc_slow(f->sig)) (ws, f);
/*where f->sig is a pointer to CilkProcInfo struct*/
```

Comment: A fine example of how awful the inside-out C type syntax is.

Comment: This is the reason function pointers are often declared with a typedef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `CilkProcInfo` structure, `inlet` is a pointer to a function that takes *an unspecified number of* arguments and does not return a value, like `void foo();`.

In the line

```
(get_proc_slow(f->sig)) (ws, f);
```

the `get_proc_slow(f->sig)` call returns this function pointer, so it is equivalent to

```
(f->sig[0].inlet) (ws, f);
```

So if your `f->sig[0].inlet` points to the function `foo()`, it is equivalent to the call

```
foo (ws, f);
```

I should admit that the `static void (*get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p)) () {...` syntax is a bit unfamiliar to me.

Comment: static void (*get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p)) () is the same as: typedef void (proc_sig)(); static proc_sig * get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p);

Comment: I am a bit confused.. if foo() doesn't take any parameters how you could pass ws and f as params? Isn't that a compiler error?

Comment: No. `void (*inlet)()` is a pointer to a function taking _unspecified_ arguments and returning no value, not _no_ arguments.

Comment: @iWerner: You can always edit your post to include corrections.

Comment: Isn't there a type mismatch between what is returned by the function and what is in declaration? I mean that the declaration says - void, but it actually returns a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Swapnil: No, the function isn't returning `void`, it's returning pointer to function returning `void`. There's no mismatch.

Comment: But in this code - static void (*get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p)) () {
     return p[0].inlet;
} 

The declaration says that it should return void. And the return statement says that it should return a pointer to a function returning void. Why is it not a type mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

get_proc_slow() returns a function pointer of type void(*)() which the code then calls. So when you do:

```
(get_proc_slow(f->sig)) (ws, f);
```

It's basically same as doing:

```
void (*fptr)() = get_proc_slow(f->sig);
fptr(ws, f);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a function that returns a pointer to a function whose return value is `void` that has no parameters (`void(*)()`) and that accepts a pointer to a `CilkProcInfo struct` as a parameter. I'm not sure why you'd need the `p[0].inlet` construct though. Couldn't you just return it as `p->inlet`?

Oh yeah, and `get_proc_slow` is the name of the function that returns said function pointer.

Comment: As it has already been noted in other comments, `()` parameter list in C does not mean "has no parameters`. It means "unspecified number of parameters".

Answer (score 0):

```
static void (*get_proc_slow(CilkProcInfo *p)) () {
     return p[0].inlet;
}
```

Reading from the name out, taking care with the grammar rules: `get_proc_slow` is a function (with internal linkage) that takes a pointer to a `CilkProcInfo` struct and returns a pointer to a function taking unspecified arguments and returning no value (`void`).

```
(get_proc_slow(f->sig)) (ws, f);
```

This statement calls the `get_proc_slow` with an appropriate parameter (`f->sig` is a pointer to a `CilkProcInfo`) and then uses the return value (a pointer to a function) to call that function with `ws` and `f` as arguments.